# Angular2 image upload with Rest

Tags: rest, api, angular

I have Rest API

I use ng2-file-upload like [this](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-file-upload/blob/master/demo/components/file-upload/simple-demo.ts)

My backend recieves following data

```
 {"file"=>"#<ActionDispatch::Http....bla bla.."}
```

When i am using rails front end - its ok. I need fix angular2. My backend is waiting data like this:

```
"photo"=>{"title"=>"qwerty", "image"=> "#<ActionDispatch::Http...blabla..."}
```

I change

```
      this.alias = uploader.options.itemAlias || 'file';
```

to

```
this.alias = uploader.options.itemAlias || 'image';
```

But I don't no how append `'photo'=>` before form. 
I deployed simple backend on heroku https://backend-file-upload.herokuapp.com/photos

Github apibackend - [this](https://github.com/AlexanderSergeevich/backend-file-upload)
Angular2 deployed - [this](https://alexandersergeevich.github.io/imageuploader/)
. If this problem be fix, I will be start to create my project. Please help.)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you take a look at [ng2-file-upload](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-file-upload).

Just tweak uploader settings and you should be good to go

```
uploader:FileUploader = new FileUploader({url: URL});
```

Documentation is a bit incomplete, so take a look at the demo.

Comment: I have tried this module and recieve error. I wrote in my topic. Can you help me???

Comment: Did you set `itemAlias` properly?

Comment: Yes, I do.But it changed only "file" to "image". I need  to append   'photo'=> before form { "image" =>}

Comment: Good news, I understended how fix problem. I change my backend controller. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40517603/rails-api-with-paperclip/40519325#40519325