# Rails api with paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby

I have rails api with simple paperclip model:

```
def create
@photo = Photo.new(photo_params)

if @photo.save
  render json: @photo, status: :created, location: @photo
else
  render json: @photo.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
end
end

private    

def photo_params
  params.require(:photo).permit(:image, :title)
end
```

My frontend framework send get like this

```
{"title"=>"simpletitletext", "photo"=>{"image"=>......}}
```

But it wrong, because rails waits following

```
{"photo"=>{"title"=>"simpletitle", "image"=>#...}}
```

I had been trying for different ways to fix angular for many hours, before wrote . May be it will be able to fix  in rails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your server has an incoming request that looks like this:

```
{"title"=>"simpletitletext", "photo"=>{"image"=>......}}
```

you can make it look like this:

```
{"photo"=>{"title"=>"simpletitle", "image"=>#...}}
```

The only difference between the two is that in the first, the `title` key is outside of the `photo` nested hash. but you want it to be inside.

So in your Rails controller,. you could write:

```
def photo_params
  hash = params[:photo]
  hash.merge(title: params[:title])
end
```

Comment: Thank you! I wrote: Photo.new( title: params[:title],image: params[:photo][:image] ) and it works fine too.